# NSPredicate with core data objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, ios7, nspredicate

I have an array which consist of core data class objects. I want to use NSPredicate (for suggestive search) to filter out a particular property of that class.

Requirement
I am having a core data classes: AlbumDetails (properties- album name, albumType,etc) 
i want to access AlbumDetails.AlbumName property using NSPredicate for my search bar text.
I currently know using predicate for simple array or dictionary structures, but how can i use predicate for a property of a particular class.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @Anil please refer edited question, is it clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"albumName contains[cd] %@", searchString];
```

Where `albumName` is the property of your class. `contains` will help you to get all the albums whose name contains the searchString

Comment: Suppose i am having an array aryAlbumList, can i use it like [aryAlbumList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]; ??? Will it be returning me filtered array of songName???

Comment: songName?? i didnt get. Suppose you have a list of albums with names [flowers,floors,cats..]. your search string is `fl`. After filtering you will get the albums [flowers,floors]

Comment: it will return the album objects whose names matches the search string. for identification i put like that